# Image resizing web service

Tags: php, python, ruby, web-services, image-processing

Does someone know a good web service to resize images ? Either an open source (PHP/Python/Ruby) application, or a company providing a web service api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're asking for a website?

http://www.picnik.com/ is what Flickr uses.

http://www.shrinkpictures.com/

Comment: Are you saying that Flicker does not process its pictures by itself ?

Thanks a lot, picnik seems exactly what I need.

Comment: Nope.  Flickr doesn't have any way to modify images on their site other than rotation.

Answer (score 4):

Make your own service at Utility Mill (http://utilitymill.com).  Here's one that I wrote that adds a simulated gallery wrap - [`http://utilitymill.com/utility/Gallery_Wrap_Image`](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Gallery_Wrap_Image).  Define your own interface, parameters, processing logic, and you get not only an interactive web service, but you also get a callable API.

Comment: It requests username and password...

Comment: Yes, the owner of that service was getting spammed to death. I think pythonanywhere might be a more current option.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is the image processing web service at [www.lightspun.com](http://www.lightspun.com) .

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides image resizing support using image magick. 
Smart Image Resizer is a PHP script ready for use. Look at http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

To build your own PHP app, look at http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.image.php

Comment: I know what can be done with PHP or Ruby with ImageMagick or GD but I'm looking for an external web-service api. I don't want this in my web app ! And if I could have resizing on-demand like gravatar as a url parameter or something similar it would be great.

Comment: I've taken a look at Smart Image Resizer it's a script and I'm looking for a standalone app/service.
Thanks for your answer answer anyway.

Comment: @Any downvoters: please provide a comment BEFORE downvoting