# Online web service for image resizing

Tags: php, service, thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image resizing web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000195/image-resizing-web-service)

many web provider have support for php but generally memory limit is very limited.
My web site needs to do image resizing, so I would have use library like gd or phpthumb, but I encounter problem with the memory limit.

So I would like to know if someone knows about an online web service that does image resizing.
Of course, a free one would be better :)

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This is not a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should have a look at timthumb http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/

It's not a service but a file you can host yourself.

Comment: Caution: Stay on top of Tim Thumb security advisories. There have been a number of [wide-spread site hacks](http://www.darkreading.com/database-security/167901020/security/news/231902162/hackers-timthumb-their-noses-at-vulnerability-to-compromise-1-2-million-sites.html) because of vulnerabilities in Tim Thumb.